# Laravel 8: Is there any way to show default form error messages inside of alert box

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, alert, laravel-8

Let's say I have a login form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="field">
        <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
        <input type="email" name="email" required>
        <label style="right:0;">Email</label>
        @error('email')
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('Something went wrong');
            </script>
        @enderror                   
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
        <input type="password">
        <label style="right:0;">Password</label>
        @error('email')
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('Something went wrong');
            </script>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

As you can see I have set a Javascript alert box for showing error messages:

```
@error('email')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Something went wrong');
    </script>
@enderror
```

Now instead of writing `Something went wrong`, I want to set Laravel default messages which is `{{ $message }}`.

But the problem is that, when I do this, it does not work!

So is there any way to show this $message inside of Javascript alert box or not ?

Comment: If you want to show the error as alert, then I suggest you to put all js code on the bottom of your html page. You can do like this  `alert('{{ $message }}');`

Comment: As advanced you can use https://github.com/yoeunes/toastr to display error, warning, danger etc. messages.

Comment: fyi, you have `@error('email')` twice in there, last one should be for password. And your `<input type="password">` doesn't have a `name` attribute

Answer (score 3):

For integrate error message to HTML code or JS code you should use curly braces like:

```js
alert({{message}});
```

**But** i'm offer use some library like [sweet alert](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert) for do this job.

Comment: I had already used that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64732894/laravel-8-how-to-use-sweet-alert-messages-for-error-reporting-of-forms/64998209#64998209

Comment: So what is the problem?
If you make sure these three step well done it should work correctly:
1) make sure sweet alert add to your project.
2) use `SweetAlert::message('Message', 'Optional Title')`;
in your controller, when you return errors.
3) use `@include('sweet::alert')` in your blade.
For more information about usage of sweet alert read the doc.